# nodejs + passport + express 3.0 + connect-flash no flashing?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using a passport-local strategy for authenticate users. I followed the guide given by Jared Hanson and installed connect-flash in order to give flash method to the req object.

One of my request handlers is the following:

```
 app.post('/login',                             
      passport.authenticate('local', {           
          successRedirect: '/'                   
        , failureRedirect: '/login'              
        , successFlash: 'Bienvenido'             
        , failureFlash: 'Credenciales no válidas'                             
      })                                         
  );
```

When the user login fails, it redirects the user to /login again but it doesnt flash anything.

I use mongodb for session storage and I see this:

```
> db.sessions.find()
{ "_id" : "qZ2eiTnx6r9LR25JOz/TGhiJ", "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"4ffb5b5db9cc16b615000001\"},\"flash\":{\"error\":[\"Credenciales no válidas\"],\"success\":[\"Bienvenido\"]}}" }
```

So the messages are inserted into the session object but they aren't pulled out. Should I do something special?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume you're pulling the messages out and rendering them in a view?  Something like:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { message: req.flash('error') });
});
```

Comment: Ok ! I actually missed this ... i feel so stupid! Thanks Jared!

Comment: @Jared I got stuck on this issue also. I think it would be really helpful to this example in the passport docs.

Comment: Yeah me too.I think it would be nice to have this in the docs.

Comment: Yep, we shouldn't have to end up on SO to work this out. In particular the fact that the `connect-flash` key is 'error' is very useful to know.